# Is there a way to get an International Driver's Permit while outside of your home country?

Tags: legal, car-rentals, automobiles, driving-licenses, permits

A Hungarian and Belgian are currently visiting my work in Australia, and they're unable to drive as their licenses aren't in English.  In theory an IDP would work, but it's unclear if there's any way for them to get one while in Australia?

Comment: The process of obtaining an IDP varies significantly from country to country. It would be more effective to ask this on a per country basis as oppposed to as a catch-all question.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk I literally said "while in Australia"?

Comment: I’m referring to country which issues drivers licenses (and the corresponding IDP). Your question mentions coworkers from Belgium and Hungary but is also asked very generically. The answer for Belgium may be radically different than the answer for Hungary.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be closed. The question is "Can they get an IDP while abroad?" and, according to the answer, the answer is uniformly "no".

Comment: @DavidRicherby the answer is yes for Canada & the US.

Comment: Tell them to get an English translation with one of the [NAATI accredited translators](https://www.naati.com.au/mynaati/PDSearch/StartNewSearch). They can show it along with their licence and Police might be lenient. Otherwise they can get a NSW licence with it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://internationaldrivingpermit.org/how-to-apply/
to obtain an IDP, you must apply before you travel in the same country that issued you a national driving license.

Comment: So - to answer the OP's question: "No".